# Issue with for each loop and arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 when running this program.

```
public class TestArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] someArray = new int[5];

            someArray[0] = 5;
            someArray[1] = 10;
            someArray[2] = 15;
            someArray[3] = 20;
            someArray[4] = 25;

            System.out.println("Array length = " + someArray.length);
            for (int i : someArray) {
                    System.out.println("Element at index " + i + ": " + someArray[i]);
            }
    }
```

}

Shouldn't the loop exit when i is greater than or equal to the length of the array which would be 5 in this case?

Comment: What do you think `i` represents in your enhanced for loop?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(someArray).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are iterating over array values itself not the indexes. Use just `i` not `someArray[i]`

Or change your loop to

```
for (int i=0; i<someArray.length; i++)
```

Changing loop is better in this case based upon what you are trying to achieve there